# plotting graph with sound in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, audio

User A will record his voice and i want to plot a graph according to his voice... is there any voice chart available...

Answer (score 0):

I have use the Bass library from un4seen.com

http://www.un4seen.com/

they have an asp.net port.

Similar question: [asp.net create waveform image from mp3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931952/asp-net-create-waveform-image-from-mp3)

Comment: i downloaded the sample... but unable to find the code achieve such a task... can u pls help?