# Generate sound wave image from mp3/wav file?

Tags: .net, audio, executable, visualization

Looking for a program / lib (preferably in .NET) that can take a sound file (mp3/wav/etc) and generate a sound wave image from it (similar to image below)

[image]
<sub>(source: [prntscreen.net](http://www.prntscreen.net/itpblog/Sound_Wave2.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215326/open-source-c-code-to-present-wave-form

Comment: Thanks! Did quite a few searches but missed that one...

Answer (score 1):

I wrapped mp3 decoder library and made it available for .net developers.  You can find it here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mpg123net/

Included are the samples to convert mp3 file to PCM, and read ID3 tags.

So, convert your mp3 file to PCM, and then compute log(max(some block)) for each vertical line.  You'll have to determine what is desired length of the 'some block' in previous sentence, according to your needs.

Comment: Interesting! Will have a look at it!